# git: determine whether a given file changed between revision hashes A and B?

Tags: git, diff

Is there an easy way in Git to determine whether a given file changed between revision hashes A and B?

I know I can do this easily if I can determine the revision hashes A' and B', where A'=predchange(A, path) and B'=predchange(B, path), where predchange(X, path) is the most recent parent of X (or X itself) where the given path was changed. Then I just check whether A' == B'.

Comment: No, it is *not* a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git diff [--stat] A..B -- path/to/file`

With `--stat`, it simply shows a one-line summary of the changes. Without, it shows the actual diff.

The `A..B` syntax is a revision range. It scans  as "All commits reachable from B, but not from A". When you pass a [revision range](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) to [diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), it shows diffs from all commits in the range. `A` and `B` are "commitish" - either SHA1's identifying commits, refs or tags, HEAD, or any of the previous combined with the special selectors such as `^`.

Comment: In fact, you can just give `git diff` the two commits without the `..` between them.  That is, `git diff A..B` and `git diff A B` do exactly the same thing.  While a range like this normally selects all commits reachable from commit `B`, excluding all commits reachable from `A`, `git diff` changes the meaning to use just the two specific commits.  (This short-cut works because each commit is a complete snapshot, rather than a set of changes from some previous commit.)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) with a [range](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges).

```
git diff HEAD^.. file.txt
```

If you see `less` empty, nothing has changed.

Comment: @JasonS It's a command that `git` often pipes data through, so you can read it in an easy way.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. I know what the `less` command-line tool is.... but you just mentioned it out of the blue with no context.

Comment: @JasonS If you ran the command, it would have been obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff <A> <B> -- <path> | wc -l
```

0 means the file was not changed.